# Selecting from the table that does many to many

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL

```
SELECT themes.theme_code, themes.name, course_themes.course_code FROM themes LEFT JOIN course_themes ON themes.theme_code=course_themes.theme_code
```

It produces the table 
[image]

As you probably understood I have the table that connect many Courses to many Themes, as you see in the table the Theme with theme_code 2 is connected to three different Courses (1,2,3), one Theme (3-code) is not connected to any course.

Is there a way, without using arrays in PHP, only in SQL to select only those Themes that are not linked to specific Course, e.g. Course with code #1. The Themes should not provide duplicate records, like if you select all Themes where course_code is not 1 or null, in that case it will show the Themes linked to other Courses, even if it's already linked to the Course that I want.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: provide test data and expected result in tabular form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, exists logic works well in this case:

```
SELECT
     t.theme_code,
     t.name
FROM themes t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM course_themes ct
                  WHERE t.theme_code = ct.theme_code AND ct.course_code = 1);
```

If you wanted to use a join approach, you could try a left anti-join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     t.theme_code,
     t.name
FROM themes t
LEFT JOIN course_themes ct
    ON t.theme_code = ct.theme_code AND ct.course_code = 1
WHERE
    ct.theme_code IS NULL;
```

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you so much for the first alternative, would you mind showing me where to read about SELECT 1 construction? Thank you again! @Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: Any decent SQL tutorial should cover exists logic, just poke around and you will find something.

Comment: Thank you Tim so much, found the it on w3s, thanks again. It is so elegant, and now I understood that you use SELECT 1 for efficiency. Kudos!